# Using bufio in Golang to blank a line of all text

Tags: go

I am using bufio and I want to erase a line.  The issue I'm running into now is I need to overwrite it with blanks and feels programmatically unsafe.  If there an idiomatic way to clear out a line in Stdout?

```
var Output *bufio.Writer = bufio.NewWriter(os.Stdout)

func MoveCursor(x int, y int) {
    fmt.Fprintf(Output, "\033[%d;%dH", y, x)
}

func Print(a ...interface{}) (n int, err error) {
    return fmt.Fprint(Output, a...)
}

Output.Flush()
scanner := bufio.NewScanner(os.Stdin)
const BLANK = "                                                      "

for {
    MoveCursor(1, 1)
    Print(BLANK)
    MoveCursor(1, 1)
    Print("Hello ", scanner.Text())
    MoveCursor(1, 4)
    Print(BLANK)
    MoveCursor(1, 4)
    Print("> ")
    Output.Flush()
    scanner.Scan()
}
```

One thing that is especially surprising is that Output.Flush() doesn't clear the entire content of the screen.

Comment: Are you sure you really want to buffer the output in such a situation? Why? Redesign.

Comment: creating a text based GUI.  Is there a better way?

Comment: Text based GUI and buffering the output doesn't mix well. Just use unbuffered output. At least for the interactive parts.

Comment: For text based UI use [termbox-go](https://github.com/nsf/termbox-go).

Comment: I'm trying to implement from scratch, but I've been reviewing their repo

Comment: Implementing from scratch without a really compelling motivation is called wasted time.

Comment: I personally disagree, I think implementing from scratch is a great way to get a better grasp of a language...  No need for the negativity.